# ruby on rails helpers html5

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-helpers

```
<%= form_for(:description, url:{action:'create'}) do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <%= f.text_field :position, data-length:30 %> 
        <label for="position">Position</label>
      </div> 
   </div>
<% end %>
```

And I got that error,

> syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block d=( f.text_field :position,
>   do data-length:30 );@output_buf ^ /home/whitehat/Documents/Books/Web
>   development/Ruby On
>   Rails/Projects/free-lance/dressing-shop/app/views/products/new.html.erb:39:
>   syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
>   ld :position, do data-length:30 );@output_buffer.safe_appen ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `data-length` to `'data-length'`:

```
<%= f.text_field :position, 'data-length': 30 %>
```